# I need to integrate Square Reader device to my c# .Net WPF application to send Request & verify payment which is better way?

Tags: square, square-connect, square-reader

I have created a WPF application and integrate checkout-api successfully for payment via payment-url.
Now I want to integrate Square Reader device so can access card payment also at same application. Please guide, suggest a proper way to integrate it.

Any way to send payment request from WPF application to SQUARE READER? Now this is my current requirement. If the terminal API works for it also?

Answer (score 0):

At this time the only way to take in person payments using a web application is with our Terminal API. If this is a mobile app you can use either [Reader SDK](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/reader-sdk/what-it-does) or [Point of Sale API](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/pos-api/what-it-does).